# Symfony2, how to pass a parameter off route

Tags: symfony, routes

Id like to know how to pass a parameter off route

**route:**

```
frontend_agences_list:
    path:     /agences/{page}
    defaults: { _controller: ProjectFrontendBundle:Frontend:listAgences, page: 1 }
```

Is it like this ?

**twig:**

```
<a href="{{ path('frontend_agences_list') }}?mode=list">
<a href="{{ path('frontend_agences_list') }}?mode=grid">
<a href="{{ path('frontend_agences_list') }}?mode=block">
```

in fact, I'd like to display results in 3 modes, **list** , **grid** and **block**. In the controller I do a test ,If **mode=list** so render "**list-view.html.twig**", elseif **mode=grid** so render "**grid-view.html.twig**" ....

Is it the good way to do this or there is another way to do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twig:

```
<a href="{{ path('frontend_agences_list', {'mode': 'list'}) }}">list mode</a>
<a href="{{ path('frontend_agences_list', {'mode': 'grid'}) }}">grid mode</a>
<a href="{{ path('frontend_agences_list', {'mode': 'block'}) }}">block mode</a>
```

Your controller:

```
public function listAgencesAction()
{
    $mode = $this->get('request')->get('mode');
    if($mode == 'list') {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I have this error `Variable "mode" does not exist...`

Comment: @hous strange... 'mode' is quoted, right? Why would be considered as a variable?

Comment: in fact, I'd like to display results in 3 modes, list , grid and block. In the controller I do a test ,If **mode=list** so render **"list-view.html.twig**", elseif **mode=grid** so render **"list-grid.html.twig"** ... Is there an aotrher method to do this ?

Comment: @house, this is not what you asked. Please edit your question in order we can give you the right answer.